# Making an Asp.Net treeview draggable: how to set a css class for Leaf Nodes only?

Tags: jquery, treeview, jquery-ui-draggable

I have an Asp.net treeview and am building the nodes programmatorically in my codebehind.

Now, this treeview is 3 levels deep, being ROOT -> CATEGORY -> Tasks belonging to this category.  I would now like to allow the user to drag these leaf tasks to another table, but only the leafs should be draggable (I'm using the Jquery draggable plugin for this, so I just need to set the css class).

Any idea how I can set the CSS class for the leaf node only (codebehind or js)? I've tried something like:

```
<asp:treeview id="treeviewTasks" runat="server"  leafnodestyle="draggable"  />
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick :(

thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was almost there, but not quite.  The correct syntax is:

```
<asp:treeview id="treeviewTasks" runat="server" leafnodestyle-cssclass="draggable hand"/>
```

RTM I guess :)